# sqlalchemy relationship one to one data repeat

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

show code:

```
class A(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'A'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
source_id = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
b = relationship('B', primaryjoin='remote(A.source_id)==foreign(B.source_id)', uselist=False)

class B(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'B'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
source_id = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

The above are two models,then we insert some data in the database to facilitate testing,
A:

```
INSERT INTO public."A" (id, source_id) VALUES (1, '21YY');
INSERT INTO public."A" (id, source_id) VALUES (2, '22YY');
INSERT INTO public."A" (id, source_id) VALUES (3, '23YY');
```

B:

```
INSERT INTO public."B" (id, source_id) VALUES (1, '21YY');
```

Now that we have inserted the data successfully, then we do the query

```
a_list = db.session.query(A).all()
for a in a_list:
    print(a.b.source_id)
```

According to common sense, only 21YY is output once, because they are one-to-one relationships, and the source_id is used for association, but the result is outputting "21YY" three times. This result needs you to help me understand, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `remote(A.source_id)==foreign(B.source_id)` with `A.source_id==foreign(B.source_id)`. Works for me.

But there is a much better way to declare One To One relationships in SQLAlchemy. You can specify foreign key when declaring column. Then SQLAlchemy will know how to join, you just specify the relationship. `primaryjoin` should be used only in special cases and your problem is not one.

See this example:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one

For your schema, that would look like this:

```
class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id = db.Column(db.String(30), db.ForeignKey("B.source_id"),
                          nullable=False, unique=True)
    b = relationship('B', uselist=False)


class B(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)
```